# Button theme and style can not apply in adapter

Tags: android, button, styles, themes

The button theme like this:

```
<style name="ButtonTheme" parent="Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button">
    <item name="colorButtonNormal">#00c4a9</item>
    <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">@dimen/user_button_size</item>
</style>
```

and the button code is:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/bt_exchange"
    style="@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
    android:layout_marginLeft="@dimen/normal_margin_32"
    android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/normal_margin_32"
    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/normal_margin_16"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:text="@string/integral_exchange_goods"
    android:theme="@style/ButtonTheme" />
```

when the code in activity layout, it can be applied, but when the code in listview item, the theme and style cannot be applied, the activity extends AppCompatActivity.
Thanks a log.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you are not applying the correct style. Your style name is `ButtonTheme` which extends from `Base.Widget.AppCompat.Button` but you are putting `@style/Widget.AppCompat.Button` as your style for the `Button` with id `bt_exchange`.

I think you should put `@style/ButtonTheme` instead.

Comment: @style/ButtonTheme does not take effect, and the code can be applied in activity layout.